# Change mirror folder in Google Drive for desktop

Tags: google-drive-file-stream, google-drive-for-desktop

Have Google Drive setup in Mirror files mode (not Stream files).
I can open the folder using **Access files from a folder on your computer** link, but is there any hidden option to change this folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to **Stream files**, restart GD, and switch back to **Mirror files**.
Option to choose folder will be there just once during this switch.